# Error when cloning a svn repository using git-svn

Tags: git-svn

I am trying to migrate a SVN repo to a git. For this I am using git-svn tool. I'm running the command:
`git svn clone [SVN repo URL] --no-metadata -A authors-transform.txt --stdlayout ~/temp`

and I'm getting the following error:

`Name does not refer to a filesystem directory: Can’t get entries of non-directory at /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/share/git-core/perl/Git/SVN/Ra.pm line 312.”`

Line 312 of that script is:

`$reporter->finish_report($pool);`
So I understand that finish_report is failing, but I don't understand why.

Answer (score 0):

That particular section in [`perl/Git/SVN/Ra.pm`](https://github.com/git/git/blame/master/perl/Git/SVN/Ra.pm#L312) is seven years old and part of the [initial split](https://github.com/git/git/commit/9f7ad1479d9ba88f175db57fba1ab704fc7b53d5) of `git-svn.perl`

Try instead [subgit](https://subgit.com/) (in its free version, for a one-shot import): it should be more robust.